# Image does not load on my webpage in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

i want to put an image in my webpage but it is not loading

the settings.py is

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    ]
```

and homepage.py is

```
<html>
<head><title>project</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="top">   
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'project1.jpg' %}">
<h1> FLIGHT</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the virtual env is sem1 final and app is project and folder named static is in project which contains project1.jpeg

i tried the django documentations but it did not work.

edit: i noticed something that may help [linux console when i open my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCIn7.png)
i think the orange color indicates some sort of error.

edit 2:i am moron it was a jpeg file not a jpg file

Comment: What does the rendered image tag look like when you inspect it?

Comment: same as homepage.html @nigel239

Comment: Can you make an example of your file tree? Where is your static folder compared to your manage.py, and where is your `settings.py` file?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, move {% load static %} to the first line of the template, then add static url at the end of your app URL patterns:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

ref: [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/)

Comment: This should only be applicable if he's not running in debug mode.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. see django docs: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: It is included by default. `If you use django.contrib.staticfiles as explained above, runserver will do this automatically when DEBUG is set to True. If you don’t have django.contrib.staticfiles in INSTALLED_APPS, you can still manually serve static files using the django.views.static.serve() view.`

Comment: It did not work.